# Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target for add dependencies in opencv module

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I get

```
Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target
```

this is my cmakelists.txt

```
set(the_description "Ascend OpenCV Pipeline")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("C:\\dev\\LibRaw-0.16.0")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("C:\\dev\\LibRaw-0.16.0\\build\\Debug")

ocv_define_module(ascend opencv_imgproc OPTIONAL opencv_highgui)

add_dependencies(ascend raw)
```

How do I do this properly. Also, how do i move the paths to the cmake properties so I can set them in the cmake gui. And what about release/debug setup? (I use cmake gui to generate visual studio solution)

Comment: To make them show up in CMake-gui, use options. Look at the "option" command.

Comment: No, `OPTION`is for bool settings only (creating a checkbox). The settings show up if you store them in the cache using `SET( LIBRAW_INCLUDE_DIR "<default_value>" CACHE PATH "include directory for libraw")`.